# java - linux serial port showing but not opening

Tags: java, linux, serial-port

i am using huawei modem to make call through java on linux machine. when i 
display available ports:-

Available port :

ttyS0: Physical Port S0 - Physical Port ;

ttyS1: Physical Port S1 - Physical Port

ttyUSB0: USB-to-Serial Port

ttyUSB1: USB-to-Serial port

ttyUSB2: USB-to-Serial Port

here **ttyUSB0**  is my COM port and **ttyUSB1** is AUDIO port. when i make call, my code open ttyUSB0 successfully and place the call. But when i open ttyUSB1 it give me the following error

```
RXTX Warning:  Removing stale lock file. /var/lock/LCK..ttyUSB0
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (ab.bc.cd.ComManager).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
OK
RXTX fhs_lock() Error: creating lock file: /var/lock/LCK..ttyUSB0: File exists
gnu.io.NoSuchPortException
OK
OK
    at gnu.io.CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifier(CommPortIdentifier.java:269)
    at ab.bc.cd.ComManager.startCall(ComManager.java:296)
    at ab.bc.cd.ComManager.sendCommandToModem(ComManager.java:254)
    at ab.bc.cd.UI.callingTo(UI.java:307)
    at ab.bc.cd.UI.gettingSingleInstance(UI.java:111)
    at ab.bc.cd.UI.main(UI.java:65)
+CPIN: READY
OK
OK
OK
OK
OK
OK
OK
```

Comment: please add the relate code

Comment: my code is working properly on window. there is no issue in code !

Comment: So, do you have permissions?

Comment: Try sudo chmod 666 /dev/ttyUSB1 before execute

Comment: i got the solution. i just plugged the modem and didn't select the device as a network it is working now.